# Как ошибку доступа авторизации по токену webapi 401 заменить пересылкой на страницу регистрации?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

aspnet 4
WebApi

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

> HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если данный метод будет вызываться где-то на клиенте то необходимо возвращать `HTTP Error 401` и уже на клиенте показывать страницу входа.

Но если у вас в проекте совмещен MVC и WebAPI, то для настройки фильтра авторизации необходимо открыть файл `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs` 
И добавить свойство `LoginPath` в:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {   
                ....
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
                ....
            });
```

Вот полный мой класс `Startup`:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // Дополнительные сведения о настройке аутентификации см. по адресу: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Настройка контекста базы данных и диспетчера пользователей для использования одного экземпляра на запрос
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            // Включение использования файла cookie, в котором приложение может хранить информацию для пользователя, выполнившего вход,
            // и использование файла cookie для временного хранения информации о входах пользователя с помощью стороннего поставщика входа
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
                SlidingExpiration = false,
                ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0) // 1 hour
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);                

            // Настройка приложения для потока обработки на основе OAuth
            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
                // В рабочем режиме задайте AllowInsecureHttp = false
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };

            // Включение использования приложением маркера-носителя для аутентификации пользователей
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        }
    }
```